# Finding a complete eigenbasis for an "entangled" Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-information, hamiltonian

Suppose we have a tensor product Hilbert space $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$ and we have a Hamiltonian defined thereon which is given by
$H = H_{1e} \otimes I+ H_1 \otimes H_2$. Suppose also we know an eigenbasis $|E_{2i} \rangle$ of $H_2$. What can we say then about the overall eigenbasis of $H$? Can we "try" eigenstates of the form $|\psi \rangle |E_{2i} \rangle$, and so find that
$$H|\psi \rangle |E_{2i} \rangle = (H_{1e}+ E_{2i}H_1\otimes I)|\psi \rangle |E_{2i} \rangle$$
and then solve this eigenvalue problem in $\mathcal{H}_1$ by considering the eigenstates $|\psi \rangle$ of $H_{1e}+ E_{2i}H_1$ in $\mathcal{H_1}$ (we see immediately that $|\psi \rangle |E_{2i} \rangle$ will be an $H$ eigenstate in this case)? **My chief concern, and the gist of this question, is how do I know I am not missing any possible $H$ eigenstates with this "trial" method?**

For example/context, in the case of a fully separable Hamiltonian, say $H = H_{1e} \otimes I+ I \otimes H_{2e}$, one can verify by explicit calculation that the product basis $|E_{1j} \rangle|E_{2i} \rangle$ are eigenstates. Then (and this is the key step which I don't know above), one can use the particular definition of a tensor product space which says that it is the vector space spanned by any product basis (a basis formed by products of bases of each $\mathcal{H}_i$). Thus, since the $|E_{1j} \rangle$ and $|E_{2i} \rangle$ are eigenkets of the self-adjoint operators $H_{1e}$ and $H_{2e}$, respectively, we have a complete eigenbasis of $H$.

---

In case this question is not clear, it is motivated by Problem 7.10 in Ballentine's quantum text, which reads:

> Two spin 1/2 particles interact through the spin-dependent potential $V(r)$
> = $V_1(r)+V_2(r)σ(1)·σ(2)$. Show that the equation determining the bound
> states can be split into two equations, one having the effective potential
> $V_1(r)+V_2(r)$ and the other having the effective potential $V_1(r)-3V_2(r)$.

Of course, the idea here is that we want to use the eigenkets of $σ(1)·σ(2)$ which were obtained in an earlier problem, but my concern is around using trial eigenstates of the form $|{\psi_0}\rangle|{1/2,1/2,0,0}\rangle$ and $|{\psi_1}\rangle|{1/2,1/2,1,0/\pm 1}\rangle$ ($|j_1,j_2,J,M\rangle$ is my notation for total angular momentum eigenstates).

P.S. I would greatly appreciate it if you can comment on why Ballentine mentions bound specifically ("that the equation determining the **bound**
states can be split into two equations" -- i.e. why bound in particular) when this seems to be general, whether we are looking for bound or unbound states of $H$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the problem in the eigenbasis $\lvert E_{2i}\rangle$ of $H_2$. Then, the Hamiltonian is block-diagonal in the basis of system $2$, with the blocks being $H_{1e}+E_{2i} H_1$. By diagonalizing this operator, you can now find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the full Hamiltonian; in particular, the eigenvectors will indeed be of the form $\lvert\psi\rangle\lvert E_{2i}\rangle$.

Comment: I am still not sure I understand, I'm afraid. You say "in the eigenbasis of $\lvert E_{2i}\rangle$", but what does that mean here when $\lvert E_{2i}\rangle$ is only an eigenstate of $\mathcal{H}_2$ but not $\mathcal{H}$? I do agree that by using the trial method I outline above, we get eigenkets $|\psi_i \rangle |E_{2i} \rangle$ where the $|\psi_i \rangle$ solve the "effective problem" which drops out once $E_{2i}$ emerges as a scalar. But I'm not sure I understand why these eigenvectors are complete. Why needn't there be any entangled eigenvectors in this basis?

Comment: @EE18 Are you familiar how to express operators in a tensor product of two Hilbert spaces (i.e. that you get a block-matrix, where each block corresponds to a basis element of one space (here H2), and describes an operator on the other space (here H1)?

Comment: I don't think so no, and perhaps that's the part of your argument which is going above my head. I mean I'm familiar with how $H_1 \otimes H_2$ acts on the tensored Hilbert space component-wise, but I don't think that's what you're referring to? Would you be able to include mention of that in your answer, or perhaps just point to a reference to consult? My textbooks have never mentioned this (I've only ever encountered dotted spin operators $\mathbf{J}_1 \cdot \mathbf{J}_2$ which are more easily solved for because of the decomposition in terms of the total angular momentum operator.

Comment: @EE18 Maybe an easier way to see that this works is by counting the number of eigenvectors you get: It precisely matches the dimension of the Hilbert space, so at least for the finite dimensional case this shows you that you obtained all eigenstates.

Comment: How would you do this counting? $\mathcal{H}$ (and $H$) here is completely general (even if we say finite-dimensional). If $\dim \mathcal{H}_2 = n_2$ we see that this trial method yields us $n_2$ equations. Let $\dim \mathcal{H}_1 = n_1$. Why should we be certain that we have $n_1$ solutions to each of these $n_2$ equations? Does one perhaps appeal to each of the "effective" Hamiltonians being Hermitian operators on $\mathcal{H}_1$, and therefore having $n_1$ eigensolutions? I suppose I can agree to that.

Comment: If there is any way to  comment on the general case I would appreciate it -- if not, happy to accept the answer as given.

Comment: Also, would it be possible to comment on why Ballentine mentions bound states in the specific problem here? I assume that we are just setting up the eigenproblem, right? And whether or not we are looking for bound states is completely irrelevant?